# Problemas con Diccionarios

Tags: python, ciclos

Estoy tratando de usar un `diccionario` como un `switch`, Mi código es:

```
a = {'1': f1(x, y), '2':  f2(x)}
while True:
    try:
        selection = getOption()
        b = a[selection]

        break

    except Exception:
        print "Error"
```

Pero tengo el siguiente problema: Si yo selecciono la opción 1, la función f2 se ejecuta, pero esto no debería suceder. ¿Como lo arreglo?

Comment: maybe should post this in stackoverflow.com the site in English, this site is

Comment: A ver, empieza ingresando un código que funcione para probar probar. Es posible que la forma de ingresar la opción sea errónea, ¿pero cómo podemos saber eso si no colocas el código de la función `getOption`?

Answer (score 3):

La clave de los diccionarios deben ser un `String`, entonces si `getOption()` retorna un entero, tu debes parsearlo a un `String`.

```
a = {'1': f1(x, y), '2':  f2(x)}
while True:
    try:
        selection = getOption()
        b = a[str(selection)]

        break

    except Exception:
        print "Error"
```

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias por responder. Pero si te das cuenta este es StackOverflow en español, por ende tu respuesta debe ser en este idioma. Si notas que la pregunta esta en Ingles puedes traducirla o sino reportarla. Saludos.

Comment: Entendido!, como vi la pregunta en ingles no quería dejarla sin ser respondida. Saludos

Comment: Los diccionarios no tienen porqué ser un `String`.... a menos que haya entendido mal, ¿qué quisiste decir con esa frase?

Comment: Lo que quise decir es que la **clave** del diccionario debe ser un String. Creo que si causa confusión ahora lo edito. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

En el momento de la definición del diccionario estás invocando las funciones `f1` y `f2`, y son los valores devueltos los que se insertan en el diccionario.

Si lo que quieres es un **switch**, un modo sería:

```
funcs = { '1': f1, '2':f2 }
while True:
    selection = getOption()
    f = funcs.get(selection, None)
    if not f is None:
      f(x,y)
    else:
      print "No existe la función"
```

Problemas:

1. Todas las funciones tienen que usar el mismo número de argumentos, aunque no usen todos los argumentos
2. Todas las funciones retornan algún valor
3. El control de errores crece a medida que aumenta el número de casos del switch, por lo que es mejor realizarlo dentro de cada función.

Por supuesto, cada uno de estos problemas se pueden evitar, pero mi recomendación es que uses estructuras `if..elif..else` y evitar propagar errores a otras partes si se puede (eg: `getOption` debería controlar sus propios errores)

```
seleccion = getOption()
if seleccion == 1:
    f1(x,y)
elif seleccion == 2:
    f2(x)
else:
    print "Selección errónea"
```

Comment: ¿y si el usuario quiere que el diccionario contenga los resultados de las funciones y no las funciones en sí? La verdad es que a partir de la 'pregunta' no queda claro.

Comment: En la pregunta se indica que no quiere que se ejecute la función f2 siempre. Con sólo los valores falta las acciones que tendrías en un `switch` en C, que supongo que es a lo que se refiere la pregunta.

Comment: A mí no me queda tan claro qué está consultando en la pregunta, demasiado amplio para mi gusto.